# Correlation coefficient returns N/A. Why?

Tags: r

I have a question regarding the correlation coefficient.
Why, if both variables are numeric, does the coefficient give me N/A? Thanks

When I test different variables in a dependent, on several occasions I get N/A as a result. This happens when I do it between a numeric dependent and independent variable.

Comment: Are there missing values in any of the variables used?

Answer (score 1):

There is likely two possible reasons

1. One of the variables is constant
2. There are `NA` in your data, if so:

In R there are two functions that compute the pearson correlation, let's see an example.

### Data

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- x;y[1] <- NA
```

There is the `cor` function

```
cor(x,y)
```

that will result in a `NA` by default. But if you change the argument `use`

```
cor(x,y,use = "na.or.complete")
```

It will result in 1. Another way is to use the function `cor.test`, that by default ignores missing values.

```
cor.test(x,y)
```

But since is a test function, the output is a list object. If you only want the coefficient. you can get the value, by:

```
cor.test(x,y)$estimate
```